# MDX Query : How I can show dummy set in query result if it is not related to other dimension?

Tags: mdx, exists

Need your help to resolve one issue in client report.

Please check the result of of 2 mdx queries below.

Note : I used Union operator so that I can merge result of 2 members with 1 (France and Germany combined).
Use Exist  function in Union because need to check first set in function if it  related to dimension member of second set.

I used Union with Exist to implement OR condition.

In first MDX query you can find dummy set (France & Germany) in result-set but in second MDX you can't find dummy (France & Germany) set because Product Category hierarchy is related to country and Exists function check that dummy set is not a actual member of Country hierarchy so it remove dummy set from the result-set.

Is there any way or alternate approach so that I can force exists function to show dummy set in final result (mDX 2)?

Is there any way or alternate approach so that I can force exists function to show dummy set in final result (mDX 2)?

MDX 1)

```
WITH 
    SET [Combined] AS {
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[France], 
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Germany]
    }
    MEMBER [Customer].[Customer Geography].[France & Germany] AS Aggregate([Combined])
SELECT
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0,
    Union(
        Except([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country], [Combined]),
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[France & Germany]
    ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Result MDX 1

```
Internet Sales Amount
Australia   $9,061,000.58
Canada  $1,977,844.86
United Kingdom  $3,391,712.21
United States   $9,389,789.51
France & Germany    $5,538,330.05
```

MDX Query 2)

```
WITH 
    SET [Combined] AS {
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[France], 
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Germany]
    }
    MEMBER [Customer].[Customer Geography].[France & Germany] AS Aggregate([Combined])
SELECT
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0,

       Union( Exists(Except([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country], [Combined]),
        {[Product].[Product Categories].[Category].&[3]}  
        , "Internet Sales") ,

      Exists([Customer].[Customer Geography].[France & Germany],{[Product].[Product Categories].[Category].&[3]}  
     , "Internet Sales"))

     ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Result MDX query 2)

```
Internet Sales Amount
Australia        $9,061,000.58
Canada          $1,977,844.86
United Kingdom  $3,391,712.21
United States   $9,389,789.51
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use exists twice in the 2nd query?

```
WITH 
    SET [Combined] AS {
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[France], 
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Germany]
    }
    MEMBER [Customer].[Customer Geography].[France & Germany] AS Aggregate([Combined])
SELECT
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0,

       Union( 
         Exists(
           Except([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country], [Combined]),
           {[Product].[Product Categories].[Category].&[3]}  
          ,"Internet Sales"
         )

        //,Exists(
        //   [Customer].[Customer Geography].[France & Germany]
        // ,{[Product].[Product Categories].[Category].&[3]}  
        // ,"Internet Sales"
        // )

        ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[France & Germany]

       )    
     ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```